# Adding onclick to a CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What would be the best way for me to take something like this CSS Flip onhover, and make it apply the CSS transition / class onclick instead.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

If someone could build a working example for me in jsfiddle, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: _"If someone could build it for me.."_. We aren't free-of-charge rent-a-coders. But we do help with _programming problems_. What exactly have you tried? Got any code?

Comment: You're correct! I'll note to post my js fiddle files in future posts. Best not to use the comment section for personal crusades so I've removed any posts that don't involve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS does not have a CLICK event. You can use JavaScript to add a class on click, and have that CSS class perform the animation.

```
.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to tempt u to throw an example into a fiddle? I should've specified that I was looking for a js example with the onclick. Thanks!

Comment: Combine this with Ibu's answer and you've got it.

Comment: Finally working, thanks! I couldn't figure out how to swap the background image for the front once the class was added, but that's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

you can create the css class that does the flip first. Then use javascript to assign it the the element in a click event.

CSS:

```
.flippingClass{
    ... flip ...
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#flipper").click(function () {
     $(this).addClass("flippingClass");
});
```